# Django ArrayField with different types

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-postgresql

I need to configure a `django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField` with a list of pairs in which the fist element is a float and the second, a small positive integer:

```
data = [[1.23, 3], [2.42, 1], [3.72, 29]]
```

How could I do this? Is it possible? I tried something like this, but didn't work:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = ArrayField(
                   models.FloatField(default=0),                        
                   models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0),
                   null=True
               )
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Can this not be solved with two floats?

Comment: I know I can solve with two floats. I just want to know if I can use different field types inside an ArrayField.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I just want to know if I can use different field types inside an ArrayField.

No, this is not possible, it would involve a very confusing way to get the data out of the database, as well as no way of really setting the field type in the database to a concrete type.

Instead, just use a two float fields

```
my_field = ArrayField(
    ArrayField(
        models.FloatField(default=0),
        size=2,
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need this functionality, you could try [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.JSONField):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = JSONField()
```

And store `'[[1.23, 3], [2.42, 1], [3.72, 29]]'` in this, though it does raise questions about the design of your data model.

Answer (score 0):

**You can Try this:**

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=1024)
   books_list = ArrayField(
       models.CharField(max_length=1024)
   )
```